# Automatically compress html and css on Publish?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I can't find a decent answer to this question. I see there are a couple other similar questions that have been asked, but they do not provide me with decent answers.

In Visual Studio, is there a way to compress all files that should be compressed (HTML, XML, CSS) automatically when the application is published?

It seems a bit pointless and wasteful to have all the extra white space, comments, and other things on the server. I have looked for different Extensions and NuGet packages, but have been unable to find anything that provides me with a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/).

> Cassette automatically sorts, concatenates, minifies, caches and
>   versions all your JavaScript, CoffeeScript, CSS, LESS, Sass and HTML
>   templates.

It's very simple to use, just read their documentation. It takes at most 5 minutes to setup.

To install, open the NuGet Package Console and type in:

```
Install-Package Cassette.Web
```

This will take care of installing, and setting things up for you.

For help or suggestion, check out their Google Group:

http://groups.google.com/group/cassette

---

There is also the option of using SquishIt. It works fine with MVC3 and serves the same purpose as Cassette. However, personally I prefer Cassette.

http://lostinthegc.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/using-squishit-in-an-asp-net-mvc3-web-application/

Answer (score 4):

Another helpful tool is **Chirpy**. I used it with VS up to 2010.
You are defining bundles with a simple XML file. It integrates into VS so if any file (css, less, js, ...) changes the minified version is automatically (re-)rendered in background.

http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/22/visual-studio-add-in-for-dotless-js-and-css-files/

With the following sample file (.chirp.config) the given CSS files are bundled and minified into two files named **external.min.css** and **internal.min.css**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <FileGroup Name="external.css">
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.core.css" />
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.button.css" />
    <File Path="css/default.css" />
  </FileGroup>
  <FileGroup Name="internal.css">
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.core.css" />
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" />
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" />
    <File Path="css/jquery.ui.accordion.css" />
    <File Path="css/default.css" />
    <File Path="css/datatables.css" />
  </FileGroup>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is:

- http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/
- http://getcassette.net/
- http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/
- https://developers.google.com/closure/  (more for JS)
- Others in this article http://thefrontend.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/minify-javascript-and-css-files-when-publishing-web-applications/

Answer (score 1):

I use the [WebMarkupMin](http://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/) package on Nuget. It has quite a nice HTML minifier which I use when generating HTML output in my program:

```
var htmlMinifier = new HtmlMinifier();
var result = htmlMinifier.Minify(myHTML, generateStatistics: false);
Console.WriteLine(result.MinifiedContent);
```